# How to download opening price before market close using quantmod package in R?

Tags: r, quantmod

I'd like to download a stock quote from Yahoo Finance while the market is still open, to acquire that day's opening price.  I'm trying to do this in R using `getSymbols()` from the quantmod package:

```
#Acquire today's data as a string
today.char <- Sys.Date() %>% as.character

#Download stock quote during market hours
currentQuote <- getSymbols('QQQ',
                           from = today.char,
                           src = "yahoo",
                           env = NULL)
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=QQQ&a=5&b=20&c=2016&d=5&e=20&f=2016&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=QQQ&x=.csv'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
  cannot open URL 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=QQQ&a=5&b=20&c=2016&d=5&e=20&f=2016&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=QQQ&x=.csv': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I obtain at least an opening price before market close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

would `getQuote()` work for you? for instance `getQuote('X')[5]` would give you todays opening price for US STEEL, and the rest of the quote is in the data frame returned by `getQuote()'